# Is it possible to test the independence of two data sets, while taking a known error into account?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, independence, agreement-statistics

I'm doing some analysis on a device which sizes potatoes. To assess the accuracy of this device, I'm comparing (1) the data for a box of potatoes, as sized by this device, and (2) the data for the same box, as sized by hand. In both cases, the raw data consists of an array of numbers. Both data sets appear to be (approximately) normally distributed.

So far, my analysis has consisted of:

- Dividing the data into bins, and carrying out a **chi-squared test**.
- Carrying out a **t-test** to compare the means of the two data sets.
- Carrying out a **Wilcoxon signed rank test**, which I understand to be a **non-parametric equivalent** to the t-test.

The device has failed - so to speak - all these tests by a very comfortable margin. However, one component of my device is known to mis-size the potatoes; it tends to overestimate them by around 5 mm. **Is there a systematic way to test the independence of the two data-sets, given that a known error may well be affecting one of them?**

Comment: If the variance of potato sizes is large, you may not have enough power to detect a real difference of size 5mm. For example, in R, code `m = rnorm(50, 10, 2);  h = rnorm(50, 10.5, 2); t.test(m, h)$p.val` returned non-significant P-value
$0.1394.$ // If you could do a run of the experiment with 50 _code numbered_ potatoes so you could run a paired t test, then power would likely be much better.